# Konva get image ID from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, konvajs

I am trying to get the ID of the image I am clicking on by using the following code:

```
theImg.on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id')); //Should show 'IDofImg'
});
```

The Konva code is this:

```
var theImg = new Konva.Image({
    image: imageObj,
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
    opacity: 0.8,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowBlur: 5,
    id: 'IDofImg',
    shadowOffset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    startScale: 1,
    shadowOpacity: 0.6,
    draggable: true
});
```

As you see, I have **id: 'IDofImg',** within the making of the image but it seems not to output the needed ID.

It currently outputs this when clicked on:

```
function() {
   // setting
   if (arguments.length) {
       this[setter](arguments[0]);
       return this;
   }
   // getting
   else {
       return this[getter]();
   }
}
```

What am I missing?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/8jv02mL3/2/)

Comment: **this.id** still produces the same results as in the OP.

Comment: Yep, **this.id()** did get the image ID just fine. Please make that the official answer so that I can give you proper credit for it.

Comment: Your welcome, added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this.id()` because it is the Konva Image object, and not an `html/javascript` object.

See also the docs: http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Node.html#id